# iPhone POST request is always seen as GET by $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] in PHP

Tags: php, ios, http

I'm doing a project on an iPhone. Here I have to send a POST request to a web service. I use a NSMutableURLRequest and a NSURLConnection to send the data, and the server uses PHP. I have found that the check `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST")` always fails, as in returns 'GET', even when I try it on localhost.

My POST request looks as follows (sniffed via Wireshark):

```
POST tester.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/tester.php
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 422

protocol=4&msgtype=authorize&merchant=86189919&language=da&ordernumber=1274168351&amount=100&currency=DKK&continueurl=http%3A%2F%2Fquickpay.net%2Ffeatures%2Fpayment-window%2Fok.php&cancelurl=http%3A%2F%2Fquickpay.net%2Ffeatures%2Fpayment-window%2Ferror.php&callbackurl=http%3A%2F%2Fquickpay.net%2Ffeatures%2Fpayment-window%2Fcallback.php&autocapture=0&cardtypelock=&splitpayment=1&md5check=d2259d9db077e0f5a41b4bf271c3c549
```

Of course there is a lot dummy text in there, that would normally not be there from a iPhone, but I have tried to make the same call via a html form, and that worked. Therefore I have copied all the information over to see if that would make a difference, but to no avail.

I have compared the two requests (one from the iPhone, the other from my php page) and they look exactly the same.

I'm flabbergasted - does anyone have a good advice on what to do?

**Edit:**

> Your test isn't testing for post or post vs get, it is testing for POST specifically, you could have a case issue there... Have you tried inspecting the request itself in php? – Grady Player

Yes, that could be true, but the line always returns GET, so the case issue is covered, if that's what you mean.

> Also, please post the result of print_r($_SERVER) from the server when the iPhone sends the request – Aleks G

Array( HTTP_HOST => 10.11.105.254 HTTP_USER_AGENT => Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9B176 HTTP_ACCEPT => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE => en-us HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING => gzip, deflate HTTP_CONNECTION => keep-alive PATH => /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin SERVER_SIGNATURE => Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch Server at 10.11.105.254 Port 80
 SERVER_SOFTWARE => Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch SERVER_NAME => 10.11.105.254 SERVER_ADDR => 10.11.105.254 SERVER_PORT => 80 REMOTE_ADDR => 10.11.105.254 DOCUMENT_ROOT => /Library/WebServer/Documents SERVER_ADMIN => you@example.com SCRIPT_FILENAME => /Users/tester.php REMOTE_PORT => 51492 GATEWAY_INTERFACE => CGI/1.1 SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.1 REQUEST_METHOD => GET QUERY_STRING =>  REQUEST_URI => /tester.php SCRIPT_NAME => /tester.php PHP_SELF => /tester.php REQUEST_TIME => 1334211212 argv => Array argc => 0 )

> Did you try checking to see if a known variable, e.g. $_POST['known_to_be_set_by_client'] is set or not? It's not PHP that figures out if a request is POST or GET, it's the web server. – Tim Post

When I try to echo a known variable from the iPhone request, it is of course empty. Which makes sense. When I echo the same thing from the form it is there.

> Post the iOS code your using to make the actual request. – Cliff Ribaudo

Here is the code that creates the request and sends it:

```
//variables
NSString *protocol = @"4";
NSString *msgtype = @"authorize";
NSString *merchant = @"86189919";
NSString *language = @"da";
NSString *orderNo = @"1274168351";
NSString *amount = @"100";
NSString *currency = @"DKK";
NSString *continueURL = @"http://quickpay.net/features/payment-window/ok.php";
NSString *cancelURL = @"http://quickpay.net/features/payment-window/error.php";
NSString *callbackURL = @"http://quickpay.net/features/payment-window/callback.php";
NSString *autoCapture = @"0";
NSString *cardtypeLock =@"";
NSString *splitText = @"1";
NSString *md5check = @"d2259d9db077e0f5a41b4bf271c3c549";

//setting up the request
NSMutableString *post = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"protocol="];
[post appendString:protocol];

[post appendString:@"&msgtype="];
[post appendString:msgtype];

[post appendString:@"&merchant="];
[post appendString:merchant];

[post appendString:@"&language="];
[post appendString:language];

[post appendString:@"&ordernumber="];
[post appendString:orderNo];

[post appendString:@"&amount="];
[post appendString:amount];

[post appendString:@"&currency="];
[post appendString:currency];

[post appendString:@"&continueurl="];
[post appendString:continueURL];

[post appendString:@"&cancelurl="];
[post appendString:cancelURL];

[post appendString:@"&callbackurl="];
[post appendString:callbackURL];

[post appendString:@"&autocapture="];
[post appendString:autoCapture];

[post appendString:@"&cardtypelock="];
[post appendString:cardtypeLock];

[post appendString:@"&splitpayment="];
[post appendString:splitText];

[post appendString:@"&md5check="];
[post appendString:md5check];


//escape characters
NSString *tmp = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                        NULL, 
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)post, 
                                        NULL, 
                                        (CFStringRef)@";/:@+$,~", 
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8
                                        );


NSData *body = [tmp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//setup url
NSString *urlString =@"http://10.10.225.255/tester.php";
NSURL *quickUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//setup URL request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
//method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//url
[request setURL:url];

//body data to string
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//content length
NSString *postLenght = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];

//set body
[request setHTTPBody:body];

//Dummy data to make the request look like the same from the HTML form.
[request setValue:@"localhost" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"en-us,en;q=0.5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:@"gzip, deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setValue:@"http://localhost/tester.php" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setValue:postLenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-length"];

//send the request to server
if([[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]){
    NSLog(@"sending data to quickpay"); 
}
```

Comment: Your test isn't testing for post or post vs get, it is testing for POST specifically, you could have a case issue there... Have you tried inspecting the request itself in php?

Comment: Post the iOS code your using to make the actual request.

Comment: Also, please post the result of `print_r($_SERVER)` from the server when the iPhone sends the request

Comment: Did you try checking to see if a known variable, e.g. `$_POST['known_to_be_set_by_client']` is set or not? It's not PHP that figures out if a request is POST or GET, it's the web server.

Comment: If you pasted the request sniff right, than your request has no request body, the "body" is part of the headers.

Comment: Hakre: Apparently a newline went missing between the Content-Lenght and the parameters (added it). I'm guessing that's what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
As expected, it was an oversight by myself!
When I loaded to url into the UIWebView, in the delegate, I used the loadRequest method, which of course uses a GET request to return the content. Instead I should have used the loadHTMLString:baseURL: method instead to load the returned data.
This error meant that the app issued another GET request after my initial POST, which caused the error. Obviously I didn't notice this extra request for a looong time.

Answer (score 1):

(This is more a comment than an answer) If

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST")
```

always fails (as you write in your question), this **must mean** that:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"
```

So either you have asked the wrong question, or you are not properly validating input values. Please add the output of `var_dump($_SERVER)` to your question.

Comment: Ohhh...stupid me - I asked the WRONG question. Of course if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") does not fail, it succeeds! 
I want it to be a POST request by PHP interprets it as a GET.

Comment: Wired. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"` according to your edit. Would be interesting to see the code that fires the request. If it really is a POST request, you probably have found some bug. Let's find out more later.

Comment: ok. Let me just arrange the code from iOS so that it is readable for other people, and I'll post it.